# IOS 8:ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova

Tags: cordova, ios8

I was developing a mobile application using cordova 3.4, and everything working well on **android** and **ios<7**.
unfortunately, the application is not working on **IOS8** and the error is  `Can't find variable: cordova`.
any help please.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same thing and noticed that I had committed out the **cordova.js** script in the **index.html** file.  After uncommenting the cordova script.  Everything worked great, and it even fixed my bouncing header caused by the keyboard coming into view.

```
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh jeez. Thank you!!! This should be put as a main headline in the documentation. For anyone else: no need to put a cordova.js file in the root, this will make cordova work!